# FreeBSD 9,1 - upowerd's cpu consumption off the roof and causes OS to restart

Tags: freebsd, cpu

I've been experiencing a really annoying problem with a FreeBSD setup on my laptop. The setup is as follows:

FreeBSD 9.1 / KDE4 desktop / Broadcom wireless 4313 through NDIS / Intel GPU with the new KMS driver.

The problem occurs some time after turning on the laptop, the desktop becomes sluggish. When checking the processes, upowerd is taking 100% cpu and cannot be killed. And either I reboot the system or it ends up rebooting on its own. And lately, such reboots are affecting the filesystem: I had to boot on live system and repair the damaged partitions.

Any pointers to what might cause this or how to prevent it ?

Comment: There is no upowerd on FreeBSD.

Comment: @Simon Where is this `upowerd` then coming from?

Comment: @Bernhard [sysutils/upower](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/upower/)